# Write a query that give different class of ip

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I save ips to a table (table has one column type varchar) and now want to select different class of ip

for example if i save below ips, want to write a query that give me result like below

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.10
5.190.8.20
5.190.8.21

Reseult :
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.1
5.190.8.20
```

Comment: There's not much point in a table with one column. Do you mean you want to see the distinct IP's?

Comment: I can't see a reason why you wouldn't do that. Go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table(ip varchar(100))

insert into @t 

values ('192.168.0.1'),('192.168.0.2'),('192.168.0.3'),('192.168.1.1'),
       ('192.168.1.10'),('5.190.8.20'),('5.190.8.21')

select * from @t

select 
    reverse(substring(REVERSE(ip), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ip))+1, LEN(ip) ))
from @t
group by substring(REVERSE(ip), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(ip))+1, LEN(ip) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to derive the below answer fro @Ajay207.

Try this

```
DECLARE @IPTABLE TABLE(IP VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @IPTABLE 
VALUES ('192.168.0.1'),('192.168.0.2'),('192.168.0.3'),('192.168.1.1'),
       ('192.168.1.10'),('5.190.8.20'),('5.190.8.21')

SELECT 
    MIN(TEMP.IP)
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        IPFIRST=REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(IP), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IP))+1, LEN(IP))),
        IP
    FROM @IPTABLE
) AS TEMP
GROUP BY TEMP.IPFIRST


output is 
----------
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.1
5.190.8.20
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8bd6/2)